# Multiple errors converting .net core to csproj

Tags: c#, msbuild, asp.net-core, .net-core

After installing VS2017 RC I realized I needed to upgrade my asp.net core project to work with csproj instead of xproj and project.json.

The upgrade went well, but now I am getting a lot of warnings, and an error.

first, there are warnings regarding the .csproj file. I am getting the following warning - even in a new core class library.

> The element 'PropertyGroup' in namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003' has invalid
>   child element 'TargetFramework' in namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'.

I am also getting

> The OutputPath is not set for project

Adding an OutputPath in the .csproj file fixes that error, but the OutputPath property is not set in the new class library project I created and it still compiles.

Even after setting the OutputPath, I am getting other errors and warnings, but they don't affect the build (however - and I can't seem to reproduce them in a new project) and even though intellisense is going crazy.

other than that - I am getting over a thousand errors in VS2015 (it can't really load the nuget packages for some reason).

It might be worth mentioning that I am trying to target both .net core and .net461

Comment: dude, just copy and paste the code into a new project, i came across same situation and found no useful way than that. hope it helps

Comment: It's a big project... kinda ruins the git versioning as well - I think I would rather going back to xproj...

Comment: If you haven't already, I recommend updating to latest VS2017 updates, including .NET Core CLI 1.0.0-preview4-004233. It contains many bug fixes, such as the a fix for the 'OutputPath' error you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You can always copy the files over into a new 2017 IDE project